# Why do the non-informative a priori distributions give better results than the frequentist estimate?

Tags: bayesian, prior, garch, hidden-markov-model, frequentist

For example, in the specific case of Markov-Switching GARCH models why is a non-informative prior distribution chosen for GARCH models with Bayesian estimation and why is this approach better than the frequentist estimation method?

Comment: Is it better?..

Comment: For example, as is reported in the abstract of "Forecasting risk with Markov-switching GARCH models:A large-scale performance study":  **Also, our results indicate that accounting for parameter uncertainty improves left– tail predictions, independently of the inclusion of the Markov–switching mechanism.**

Comment: I have read the same abstract but cannot see how one could derive your title claim for it. But perhaps it is deeper in the paper. The question is, how general the study is and whether the authors are unbiased towards frequentist vs. Bayesian approaches (in my experience, authors are often biased). So I would hesitate to make the claim as general as it is. I am not saying it is necessarily wrong, but some more support would be needed for it to make worthy an investigation into the causes of it.

Comment: What is rather obvious is that accounting for estimation imprecision of parameters makes forecasts better, especially if these forecasts are not targeting the conditional expected value of the variable. If the frequentist methods applied are not accounting for that, they are at a disadvantage. However, this is not necessarily due to their frequentist nature as there are tools also within the frequentist paradigm to account for estimation imprecision of parameters.

Comment: The paper highlights the result as the Bayesian estimate, which therefore takes into account the distribution and uncertainty of the parameters without making assumptions, leads to making better forecasts of the VaR, i.e. the left tail of the distribution. We would expect both estimates to lead to the same result being the non-informative prior distributions. Why, on the other hand, is there a slight difference in estimating the parameters of the GARCH model in your opinion @RichardHardy?

Comment: I am no expert in Bayesian stuff, but I doubt this Bayesian estimator is exactly the same as the frequentist one. They may be approximately the same, hence the slight difference. Moreover, there could be numerical approximations going on, resulting in those slight differences.