# For GARCH model Bayesian estimation is better than ML estimation

Tags: bayesian, estimation, maximum-likelihood, garch, frequentist

In the work of

> [Ardia] - Financial Risk Management with Bayesian Estimation of GARCH
>   Models_ Theory and Applications

in which the Bayesian estimation method with **uninformative prior** distributions is compared the frequentist estimation method, it results that the first approach gives better results as regards the family GARCH models, in terms of forecasts, one step from the left tail of the distribution of returns.

This happens because the posterior distributions of the parameters of the GARCH model
$$\sigma_t^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 y_{t-1}^2+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2$$

are asymmetric, and this implies that the Gaussianity assumptions, necessary for the ML estimate, are too weak, as you can see from the following figure which concerns a Markov-Switching jgrGARCH model with 2 regimes
[image]

If they were true, with an uninformative prior  distribution, the ML estimate and the Bayesian estimate should give the same result, exactly?

Comment: (Caveat: I am a novice in Bayesian statistics, so my comment might be stupid.) ML makes assumptions about the error term (or in GARCH terms, standardized innovations) of the model. How is that related to distributions of parameters? In a frequentist setting, there are no such distributions; parameters are not modelled as random variables. You could only consider distributions of estimators of parameters. These are nonlinear functions of the errors, hence you would not expect normality in finite samples (but would perhaps expect it asymptotically). I miss the connection between Bayes and freq.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I connect to your reasoning by quoting an extract from the same text that analyzes the two approaches for estimating GARCH models:

Comment: "In Fig. 7.9, we display the marginal densities obtained via Gaussian kernel density estimates, for the model parameters obtained through the Bayesian approach (in solid lines) and the ML approach (in dashed lines). From these graphs, we note that the ML estimation leads to more peaked density estimates and therefore underestimates the parameter uncertainty. Furthermore, compared to the Bayesian approach, the ML approach underestimates the values of the components of vector $\alpha$ whereas the components of  $\beta$ are overestimated".

Comment: So in your opinion, in this case, therefore, is the asymptotic hypothesis of normal distribution wrong, ie are the hypotheses underlying the Central Limit Theorem invalid?

Comment: This looks like the finding quoted in [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422229/): the estimated (conditional) density of the *dependent variable* is less concentrated when parameter uncertainty is taken into account (in the Bayesian case) then when not (in the frequentist case). I.e. I suspect the latter quote might regard density of the dependent variable rather than parameter estimators. Or does it not?

Comment: Sorry @RichardHardy but it is still not very clear to me: so the fact that the parameters are not independent leads to not being able to make the assumptions underlying the search for the maximum of the likelihood function? PS. I added some more details to the question

Comment: From a frequentist perspective, parameters are constants, so terms like *independent parameters* are not meaningful. Also, comparison of Bayesian vs. frequentist results is inherently complicated; I am not sure one can meaningfully draw posteriors on top of asymptotic Normal approximations like that. Frequentist estimation does not yield distributions of parameters, so what are those Normal approximations? Are these confidence distributions actually fiducial distributions? I do not have the time to read the paper, so I doubt I will be of much more help.

Comment: The Bernstein-von-Mises theorem describes the posterior distribution as being normal, asymptotically, and there are similar results describing the asymptotic distribution of MLE estimates as being normal as well. Yes, if you have noninformative priors and a lot of data, it's not uncommon to end up with similar results, whether you're a Bayesian or frequentist.

Comment: However, both of these theorems have a lot of regularity conditions that might not hold. To answer your question, you need to look at these in detail. There was a Wald lecture that describes a few cases where results are quite different: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1017938917